# Private Ethereum Blockchain and Parity w/ Proof-of-Authority

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, parity, proof-of-authority

Can someone point me in the right direction.  I want to set up a private Ethereum network using Parity w/ Proof-of-Authority to avoid mining.  I've found an example with Geth, but can't find a good example with Parity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Demo-PoA-tutorial](https://github.com/paritytech/wiki/blob/master/Demo-PoA-tutorial.md) which demonstrates how to setup a PoA network of two nodes.